# SED syntax to insert a string between two line numbers?

Tags: sed

For example, in a text file /location/file.txt:

```
some random text
some more random text
some more random text
```

I would like to insert a string of words in between the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two insert between 2 and 3 (after `2`):

```
sed '2{a\
two words
}' input
```

To insert between 1 and 2 (before `2`):

```
sed '2{i\
two words
}' input
```

Or if you don't want newlines:

```
sed '2a\\ttwo words' input
```

Comment: And input gets changed to /path/file.txt?

Comment: yes, and if you want to do in-place replacement then add the `-i` option

Comment: sed '36{a\two words}' /var/www/mysite/test.php, comes that error

Comment: you need to have a newline after `a\ ` and before `}` as in the examples above.

Comment: I can only use sed from a single command then have to run it again before the next command, is there a syntax that includes the new lines? I mean I can't carriage return.

Comment: Create a file named `words` and write the `two words` in it. then do `sed '2r words' input`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22289/discussion-between-user1166981-and-perreal)

Comment: Hmm its odd, the changed result is sent back to the screen by sed, but the actual file doesn't change. I have chmod the file 777 for testing, why would that be do you think?

Comment: use `sed -i '2a\\ttwo words' input`

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '{print} NR==2{print "here is some extra text after line 2"}' file
```

If you want to overwrite the original file:

```
awk '{print} NR==2{print "here is some extra text after line 2"}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add one line "new line here" between the second and third line.

```
awk 'NR==3{print "new line here"}1' your_file
```

if you want to do it inplace use
perl:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "new line here.\n" if($.==3)' your_file
```